# SQL equivalent of 'this' ABL statement

Tags: sql, vba, aggregate, progress-4gl

Someone might understand this ABL statement...

```
FOR EACH <table> BREAK BY <field as breakgroup>: 
   ....
   IF FIRST-OF(<breakgroup>) THEN DO:
       ....
   END.
   ....
   IF LAST-OF(<breakgroup>) THEN DO:
       ....
   END.
   ....
END.
```

Above code basically loops through individual records in a table and then runs some codes (....) during specific parts of the execution. Interesting to note is the FIRST-OF and LAST-OF statement where the `<breakgroup>` value changes and is useful for data aggregation.

Does someone know how to implement/replicate the same logic using SQL perhaps with some VBA as well?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it is worth noting that SQL, contrary to the OpenEdge ABL, is not a 4GL. It's not supposed to 'execute code' per se, so you will have to use another programming language to execute SQL statements against a Database, retrieve the selected records and then manipulate them with whatever language you might be using.

To get the equivalent of an ABL FIRST-OF or LAST-OF statement, the SQL FIRST() and LAST() function will come in handy ([First()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_first.asp) and [Last()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp) explain those.)

Basically, that means that you will have to do at least three different SQL Select statements I think, on to select all the table entries you want, one to select the first one of a given 'group' (a group, after all, is just a subselection of entries that fulfill certain criteria) and one to select the last one of such a group. For Example

```
SELECT LAST(CustomerType) WHERE CustomerType = "ValuedCustomer"
```

Now, if you want to use VBA as your programming language, you can execute SQL statements for instance with a command like this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT LAST(CustomerType) WHERE CustomerType = 'ValuedCustomer'"
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff194626.aspx) is the MSDN entry for that command!

Hope that helped!